# Antlr3, C# and VS 2012 Express

Tags: c#, .net, antlr3

I'm working with the Antlr3 Runtime in VS 2012 Express and while trying to build the project, I am getting the following errors from the generated:

```
C:\dev\projects\vs\ANTLR\T\obj\Debug\TParser.cs(587,23,587,29): error CS0102: The type 'T.TParser' already contains a definition for 'Follow
C:\dev\projects\vs\ANTLR\T\obj\Debug\TLexer.cs(2587,16,2587,20): error CS0102: The type 'T.TLexer' already contains a definition for 'DFA7'
```

I have tried searching everywhere for anything on this but it seems that there is no mention of this anywhere. Can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an error C# in target generation OR in ANTRL itself.
It is not clear which ANTLR version you use.
In cases like this, you could try a newer version or earlier version oF ANTLR.
OR have a look what is defined again and fix the generated code yourself.

Comment: I'm working with ANTLR 3.4. I tried reverting back to ANTLR 2 and it was just a mess in VS 2012. I've been having a lot of issues integrating ANTLR into the 2012 edition. For example, I can't get the C/C++ runtimes working with it. Though, I think I got it figured out. Well, not figured out but 'fixed' I erased the project and solution and started from scratch.